# Javascript clearInterval and setInterval() acting not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

```
var timer = 0
var startInterval = function( value ) {
    timer = setInterval( "checkNewPost();", value );
}
var stopInterval = function() {
    clearInterval( timer );
}

jQuery("#centerColumn a").click(function() {
    var a_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var splitValue = a_id.split("-");
    var newValue = splitValue[1];

    if( newValue == "30" ) { 
        stopInterval;
        startInterval( 10000 );
    }
    else if( newValue == "1" ) {
        stopInterval;
        startInterval( 20000 );
    }
    else if( newValue == "5" ) {
        stopInterval;
        startInterval( 30000 );
    }
    else if( newValue == "pause" )
        stopInterval;
});
```

As you can see in my code, the logic is pretty straight forward, when newvalue is equal to 30 it will stop the current interval and restart it with a 10000 seconds on the setInterval. And when newValue is equal to pause, it will stop all the setInterval.

The problem here is it does not act correctly, i'm not sure why? Can someone guide me on this. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to call the stopInterval function

```
stopInterval();
```

I think it won't work without the parentheses

Comment: This is correct. `stopInterval` is a reference to the function, `stopInterval()` is *calling* the function. The former, used as a statement of its own has no real meaning just as `myVariable;` doesn't mean anything. However, referencing a function without calling it is useful when doing things like `var callback = stopInterval(); ... callback();` or `stopInterval = (new function declaration)`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
 stopInterval; // fonction simply put on stack
```

with

```
 stopInterval(); // fonction call
```

Answer (score 2):

Your calls to `stopInterval` are missing the parentheses after them so you're currently not actually calling that method.

Try using `stopInterval();`

Answer (score 1):

Everybody else is right, you should use `stopInterval()`. Also here's a more compact and IMO more readable version of your code:

```
$('#centerColumn a').click(function () {
    var id = this.id.split('-')[1];
    var value = {
        30: 10000,
        1: 20000,
        5: 30000
    };
    id ==== 'pause' && stopInterval();
    if (value[id]) {
        stopInterval();
        startInterval(value[id]);
    }
});
```

Comment: readable? sugar! ... `id ==== 'pause' && stopInterval();` every time you stop by this line you have to think about it - it's less code, but not cleaner! (whereas the idea with the enum is nice ...)

Comment: I guess it depends... `id ==== 'pause' && stopInterval()` is readable to my eyes...